# iOS Custom Keyboard Height Launching Glitch

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, custom-keyboard

I have created a custom keyboard and it works fine. I set the height constraint to be the same as the default keyboard. The issue is that when the keyboard first launches, it starts off below the keyboard and then positions itself to the correct height.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

I attached two images of the launch as it is launching and after it has launched:

[At Initial Launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqe7s.jpg)

[Once Launched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfIPC.jpg)

I am hardcoding the view height.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    if UIScreen.main.bounds.width < UIScreen.main.bounds.height {
        if UIScreen.main.bounds.height == 667 ||
            UIScreen.main.bounds.height == 812 {
                viewHeight.constant = 216
            } else {
                viewHeight.constant = 226
            }
    } else if UIScreen.main.bounds.width > UIScreen.main.bounds.height {
        if (UIScreen.main.bounds.height == 375 && UIScreen.main.bounds.width == 667) || UIScreen.main.bounds.height == 812 || (UIScreen.main.bounds.height == 414 && UIScreen.main.bounds.width == 736) {
            viewHeight.constant = 158
        } else {
            viewHeight.constant = 168
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without seeing your code.

If I understand you correctly:

- You set the height constraint to be the same as the default keyboard
- On first launch the keyboard is displayed incorrectly
- On subsequent launches the keyboard is displayed correctly

This could have 2 causes:

1) When setting the height constraint on first launch, the value you set is different than the value you see on subsequent launches. Verify that the value you set for the height constraint on first launch is the same value you set as the value you set on subsequent launches and the value the height constraint effectively has on subsequent launches. You can do that by inspecting the layout and/or logging the height constraint values.

2) When the value you set for the height constraint on first launch is the same value you set on subsequent launches and the same value the constraint effectively has, but it is still displayed different, then it may be a layouting issue. Verify that you set the value of the height constraint in the right place of the layouting process, that you properly inform the layout engine that the value has changed and the layout engine has enough time to render the change without getting interrupted.

General approaches:

- Take out complexity until your code gets so simple that you have a better chance of nailing down the issue. For debugging, instead of the nested `if`s set the height to a fixed value and see if the layout still changes on every launch.
- Try other custom keyboard projects you find online and see if these exhibit a similar behavior, maybe that gives you a hint.
- Make sure you understand how iOS auto-layout works and research if necessary. This can be quite a complex topic. The code in your question only tells so much, but for auto-layout, view hierarchy and when/where you influence the layouting process in other parts of your code are important aspects. Without seeing the whole view and code structure, this issue is difficult to analyze.
- Simplify your project as much as possible and make a demo available on Github that you can reference here, so other people can reproduce the issue.

Comment: So the interesting thing is that this doesn't happen on iPhone 8/8plus/SE. Even with an empty xib file that has no constraints or anything it does this. I've also downloaded other custom keyboards from the app store and noticed the same thing. I am thinking this is an Apple issue and not a code issue?

Comment: Does this only happen on the simulator or also on real devices?

Comment: Simulator and real device. I discovered that the more I add to the xib file the slower the loading becomes. Even with one button it glitches but repositions quickly. By the time I finish adding the buttons the keyboard takes longer to get to right position. Ideally I would want it to load at the right place.

Comment: Did you check the value of default keyboard height? Is the value wrong but the lay-outing correct or the value correct and the lay-outing wrong?

Comment: The keyboard height for an iPhone 8Plus and iPhone 11 Pro Max is the same....266. My keyboard height is also set to 226. This issue doesn't happen with the iPhone 8Plus. Not sure what you mean by the value and layouting. Is there a way to check for this? As far as I can tell they are both correct.

Comment: Please take another look at my answer, I extended the explanation there. Again, I want to point out that your question should contain the code that is at the core of your question, according to the community guidelines. It would make it easier for others to give you an helpful answer.

Comment: Also note that in your earlier comment you wrote "... 266. My keyboard height is also set to 226." The numbers are not equal, I assume this is a typo?

Comment: yes that was a typo. I added relevant code i'm using on original post.

Comment: Just to clarify....usually the first time I launch the keyboard it loads fine. Then when I toggle between keyboards it launches funky.